# Django not providing CSRF token for AngularJS frontend

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, cookies

I'm trying to send a cross domain `PUT` request from AngularJS frontend to Django backend. It's all fine when I'm running on the same domain (frontend at `localhost:8000` and backend at `localhost:8001`), I'm getting my `csrftoken` from `$cookies` and can send a successful request. The problem begins when I switch the backend to an external QA server. I get empty `$cookies`, no `sessionid` nor `csrftoken` cookies at all. I ran out of ideas and that's why I'm asking for help here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to get cookies on other domain because all cookies are set per domain, this is for security reasons.

If you want to access session and cookies in other domain, you must copy them. You can do it by sending some request with special token (for validation) and create view in django that will fetch data from some storage, based on that token and populate user cookies, so on next request they will be available.

Comment: So that's the case, thanks for clarifying this! Have a good day!